# Is it called "school diary"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In some countries, a parent is often given a small notebook that records or comments or notes some achievements or failures or feedback of his/her child by the school and students don't like these books so much.

The purpose of the book is to keep tracks of student achievements or failures, and let parents be updated of their children's study.

It might contain marks passed and failed. And so students hate it very much.

The school will give the book directly to parents one a month or a quarter and parents need to sign off and return it back to school.

**What is the book called?**

- school diary
- student book
- parent-teacher connection book
- grade book
  etc

Comment: What country?? That could make a difference.

Comment: They were called report cards when I was Young Brixtonian.

Comment: This is not necessarily universal; please indicate where you've seen this used. Anecdotally, my mother was a teacher for many years, and while she did something similar using a notebook (sometimes labelled a "composition book") in which the students were also expected to write their homework assignments, many of her colleagues even in the same school and on the same grade handled this function otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure that we have a name for these books in US English, because we don't have these books in our school system.  It sounds a little bit like a report card, but a report card is a different item every time, not one book that gets passed back and forth.

Comment: We had those at Alleyn's when I was there 1963-1970, and we called it a **journal**.

Comment: Not a school diary.  That would be a notebook that pupils use to write down the dates of tests or when homework is due..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for either the term  “progress report” or “report card”.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_card) describes report cards (which seem to be called just *reports* in British English):

> In most places, the report card is issued by the school to the student or the student's parents once to four times yearly. A typical report card uses a grading scale to determine the quality of a student's school work.

In my experience, report cards have the official grades, while a progress report could just be an update on what the grades are halfway through the marking period or some unofficial report on how the student is doing.

Report cards and progress reports (when I was a child) were printed on sheets of paper and put in an envelope. It was never an entire notebook.

Comment: so, in that case, can I just say "**report notebook/ booklet**"?

Comment: can we make it clearer by saying "**student report card/booklet**" or "**school report car/booklet**"?

Comment: @Tom “report card booklet” seems like the best option if you want to specify that it’s a booklet. If the expression you’re using doesn’t have the full phrase “report card” in it, it’s just not clear enough. (Also note that report cards are traditionally given in school to students so adding “school” or “student” is a bit redundant.)